# How to get indexPath when I search data in the function that prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, segue, uisearchcontroller

I have a problem.
I have a tableView and searchController.
When I search "C",I get two data that title of name have "C". 
But when I press the cell, the detailView present wrong infomation for me.

```
NSArray *searchResult;
UISearchController *mysearchController;


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"getDetail"]) {

    if (searchResult != nil) {

        DetailViewController *detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

        NSIndexPath *indexPath =  [searchResult..............];
        NSDictionary *item = searchResult[indexPath.row];
        detailViewController.detailName = item[@"name"];
        detailViewController.detailLocation = item[@"address"];


    }else{

        DetailViewController *detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = self.listTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;
        NSDictionary *item = self.InfoArray[indexPath.row];
        detailViewController.detailName = item[@"name"];
        detailViewController.detailLocation = item[@"address"];

    }
  }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: show full code `NSIndexPath *indexPath =  [searchResult..............];`

Comment: `[theTableViewUsedToShowSearchResults indexPathForSelectedRow]` doesn't work?

Comment: Can you show the code of perform segue and your searchResult array initialization.

Comment: @imbeginner_sorry If my answer, then correct kindly appreciate my efforts with accept the answer as right.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the Indexpath in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` `delegate` method of `UITableview`.
So your code look like this,

**Sample Code:**

```
NSArray *searchResult;
UISearchController *mysearchController;

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //code here for select the cell amd put the name of the SegueIdentifier
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"getDetail" sender:indexPath];
}
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"getDetail"]) {

        if (searchResult != nil) {

            DetailViewController *detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

            NSIndexPath *indexPath = (NSIndexPath *) sender;
            NSDictionary *item = searchResult[indexPath.row];
            detailViewController.detailName = item[@"name"];
            detailViewController.detailLocation = item[@"address"];


        }else{

            DetailViewController *detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

            NSIndexPath *indexPath =  (NSIndexPath *) sender;
            NSDictionary *item = self.InfoArray[indexPath.row];
            detailViewController.detailName = item[@"name"];
            detailViewController.detailLocation = item[@"address"];

        }
    }

}
```

Hope it works :)

Let me know if any issue.

Comment: Thanks your advice,but i use this get another wrong.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ListTableViewCell row]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff9928a4400'

Comment: In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` I belive,you have passed the indexpath not indexpath.row?? is it right?

Comment: Where your exception point is stopped, I mean to say in which Method you got the crash?

Comment: I add the exception breakpoint.Then i stop in the method -prepareforsegue

Comment: in this code: NSDictionary *item = searchResult[indexPath.row];

Comment: yes,the method -didSelectRowAtIndexPath I follow your step.

Comment: Can you share with me your .h and .m file for that viewcontroller?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122469/discussion-between-ravi-b-and-imbeginner-sorry).